# Where are the error codes defined?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I am getting error code 13 when calling `stopApplication`, this arrives on `IVideoCastConsumer.onApplicationStopFailed` . It was working fine earlier today so I don't know what changed. Anyways, where do I find what error code 13 means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the error. If you see an error code in the Cast related portion, most likely it is defined in [CastStatusCodes](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes.html)

Comment: I'm going to guess most of them come from the receiver so they probably are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your errorcode 13 is a [Unknown error](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes.html#UNKNOWN_ERROR)...

Comment: Yeah, that sucks, was hoping for something more specific. I did notice after a chromecast reboot the error went away.